# My fifteen year anniversary/My 15th anniversary at the company

Tags: idiomatic-language

Three months ago it was **my fifteen year anniversary** at the company so I received **this** gift basket. It was a very nice gift basket, but i'd just expected a pay rise or at least some kind of bonus instead.

First question:

Did a search on Google and found a lot of **my 10th anniversary at the company**, which I assume must be 10 years at the company. Is that generally a more natural way to write/say this, leaving out **year**?

Second question:

Is it natural to say **this** instead of **a** even though the speaker is not pointing at the gift basket or showing it to the one he's saying this too?

Answer (score 1):

An anniversary implies a number of years, so "10th anniversary" is correct and "10th year anniversary" is almost redundant -- it could have been your 10th month anniversary, but those are not normally recognized. But if all you use is the number, without the "th" or its equivalent, then you need to put in the 'year'. We don't generally have constructions where nouns follow each other, especially not one noun that modifies another, so the "th" convention is way of making an adjective out of the number.

It is natural to say "this gift basket", even without pointing to it or having it present. It's equivalent to saying "a gift basket"; the wording reinforces the idea that it is nice, but that something more had been expected.